# Incorrect plotting of Daily high/ low data on a smaller timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to plot the daily High/Low/Open/Close values on a 5-minute timeframe chart using pine script. The lines are only plotted correctly for real-time data but show the previous days High/Lows on historic data.

If you look back even 10-15 minutes on a 5-minute chart, you'll see the High/Low values for the previous day.

If this is the case, then backtesting strategies involving daily change calculations would be inaccurate.

Is there another way to do this, or have I done something wrong?

This is on crypto data.

Here's the code to test.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="DailyChange", shorttitle="DailyChange", overlay=true, initial_capital=1000, calc_on_every_tick=true)

DailyClose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1D', close)
DailyOpen = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1D', open)
DailyHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1D', high) 
DailyLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1D', low) 

plot(series=DailyOpen, color=color.blue, linewidth=1)
plot(series=DailyClose, color=color.red, linewidth=1)
plot(series=DailyHigh, color=color.yellow, linewidth=1)
plot(series=DailyLow, color=color.gray, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep track of the intraday values, use `var` variables instead and update them on each bar.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="DailyChange", shorttitle="DailyChange", overlay=true, initial_capital=1000, calc_on_every_tick=true)

is_new_day = ta.change(time("D"))

var float DailyClose = na
var float DailyOpen = na
var float DailyHigh = na
var float DailyLow = na

DailyClose := is_new_day ? close[1] : DailyClose
DailyOpen := is_new_day ? open : DailyOpen
DailyHigh := is_new_day ? high : high > DailyHigh ? high : DailyHigh
DailyLow := is_new_day ? low : low < DailyLow ? low : DailyLow

plot(series=DailyOpen, color=color.blue, linewidth=1)
plot(series=DailyClose, color=color.red, linewidth=1)
plot(series=DailyHigh, color=color.yellow, linewidth=1)
plot(series=DailyLow, color=color.gray, linewidth=1)
```